# Insert data to a specific mysql column from file

Tags: mysql, file, insert, phpmyadmin

I have a text file with a list of ip addresses. I need to insert this list inside a mysql table into a column named addresses. Is there a way to do that through phpmyadmin (or any other way really)?

Comment: Also, each ip address needs to be a separate row. The other column that is there named "id" which is a AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064495/inserting-a-column-to-preexisting-table-in-phpmyadmin