# Phpmyadmin, how to link tables

Tags: mysql, insert-into

Hello everyone this is my first question so if you miss something or if i am doing something wrong tell me!

I have two tables:

```
klanten:
id, ledenpagina_id

topics:
id, onderwerp, slogan, omschrijving
```

I want to add the `ledenpagina_id` to the `topics` table but I don't know how. I think it has something to do with `Insert into` but I looked up a few things but I cant get it to work in my case.

Please help me. :)

Comment: You should post relevant code here, so others can see what you are working on and what you have achieved on your own.

Comment: @rainer well its kinda hard to post the code I have because it are databasetables?

Comment: What columns and data values you expect on the updated table? Is ledenpagina_id = topics.id?

Comment: Have a look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064495/inserting-a-column-to-preexisting-table-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: @anonyXmous I think the thing he wants is to add the ledenpagina_id from the table "klanten" to also be in the "topics" table

Comment: Thanks tom. How lapenpagina id relates to topics table?

Comment: I thought the same but I think that ledenpagina_id needs to be set so he can set if ledenpagina_id = 1 show it and maybe when its 0 some people can not see it? i think that how he wants it @anonyXmous