# MySQL ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN OPTIMIZATION

Tags: mysql, alter-table

In a MariaDB Database, I'm trying to:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
ADD COLUMN `field1` BIGINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `field2`;
```

It is a great table with millions of registers (records). The DDL command runs for a long time. I don't mind if `field1` is placed at the end or not.
In performance terms, is better to place it at the end or not?

Comment: I don't get the downvotes. It is a good question IMO.

Comment: I don't think ordering coloums in mysql matters in terms of performance, it's possible duplicate question of below one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111958/does-column-order-matter-in-your-mysql-tables

Comment: I mean performance executing the ALTER TABLE command