# Order of columns creation in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

Is it important for any of the reasons if I create column A before column B in SQL Server database? No other actions are presumed in between.

Comment: What does "important for any of the reasons" mean? What reasons?

Comment: What reason?  It should not matter order, you can place the columns in the order you want, when you query.

Comment: There are some real [corner cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894522/is-there-any-reason-to-worry-about-the-column-order-in-a-table/894545#894545) where it matters.  But you are unlikely to encounter them.

Comment: Yes, because that's the order in the specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:

Your Table Structure:

```
create table test (id int, name varchar(100));
```

Table of your customer:

```
create table test (name varchar(100), id int);
```

If you use:

```
insert into test values (10, 'Roger')
```

without specifying the order of fields in the table will cause your customer conversion error.

Comment: You just change the order which you insert. `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)...`

Comment: yes. this was an example to show the importance of sorting tables.

Comment: Agreed with @njk, you shouldn't be inserting without a column list, or promoting this type of syntax, for precisely this reason (and also because the table may have changed in the meantime). https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx

Comment: @Roger: thanx, that should be enough to prove that it does matter - was it extreme case or not. The rule is - extremes do occur one way or the other.