# Is SQL SELECT faster if called in right order?

Tags: sql, database

Assume we have a table:

```
|   col1   |   col2   |   ....  |  coln   |
-------------------------------------------
|    -     |    -     |    -    |    -    | 
|    -     |    -     |    -    |    -    | 
|    -     |    -     |    -    |    -    | 
-------------------------------------------
```

a query where the columns are ordered:

```
$query1 = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, ..., coln FROM table";
```

and a query where the columns are unordered:

```
$query2 = "SELECT col180, col1, col78, col13, col930, col2 FROM table";
```

Is one of the queries faster than the other? Why would it be faster? Or, why isn't one faster?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: Shouldn't matter at all

Comment: Use the query log and check the time ;) I think regardless of its place in the table if you select field by field

Comment: no, it should not matter (in most cases :)): http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33984/27819

Comment: This question is not a duplicate (at least of the stated question) because it does not specify the database.

Comment: There is a difference, Similar usecase. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1008278

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should make a very small impact on performance. Here is [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271766/does-column-ordering-affects-performance-in-microsoft-sql-server-2012) by [spencer7593](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107744/spencer7593) that explains in detail:

> The order of columns in a table will have a very small impact on
> performance, as compared to the performance impact of your database
> design (entities, attributes and relationships), your transaction
> design and your query design.

Comment: It should be "a very small impact on performance", NOT a noticeable difference!!!

Comment: ^^ What I meant.  My apologies.  I edited my response.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Very good point @neubert.  I have edited the response.  Thank you.